# Repetitive code

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor1" runat="server">

<CssFiles>

<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>

 </CssFiles>


</telerik:RadEditor>


<telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor2" runat="server">

<CssFiles>

<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>

 </CssFiles>


</telerik:RadEditor>


<telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor3" runat="server">

<CssFiles>

<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="../Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>

 </CssFiles>


</telerik:RadEditor>
```

How do I get rid of this repetitive code? I need to define "CSsFiles" somewhere in my code only once and not thrice like above, then use that function or whatever for ALL the Editor  controls on my page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a web user control which wraps the RadEditor, and use that instead of using the RadEditor directly.

Comment: I just want to define "CSSiles../CSSFiles" code somewhere once..All the editors on my page have diff properties set on them...I havent typed those here...ONLY "CSSiles../CSSFiles" code is same in ALL Editors..how do I define it on my page once and then use it in all of my editors?

Comment: the user control can have properties that it can pass to the radeditor, you could also try setting the EditorCssFile value in code or a databinding expression for the css path

Answer (score -2):

Is this a real question?

First, how about you delete the duplicates?

Second, use a "UserControl" to reuse the definition of RadEditor.

Comment: Note @CRice above, who gave the same answer and didn't act like an equine posterior while he was at it.